# Rails nested model / JSON request construction confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got a two types of rails objects posts and comments. Let's say each post `has_many` comments, and each comment `belongs_to` a post.

When I construct my comment JSON string I do this:

`{"id":0,"title":"something","body":"something","post_id":1}`

but I get back

`{"id":0,"title":"something","body":"something","post_id":NULL}`

I am sending the POST json request to: `/comments.json` because in this case the Post object is a singleton.

Here are my routes:

```
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
```

Anybody know what I can fix here?

Comment: `post_id` might be protected. Try adding it to the `attr_accessible` in your comments model.

Comment: @klump That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you can not massasign the `post_id`.

You could allow massasignment just for the `post_id` by adding this line to your model:

```
attr_accessible :post_id
```

Check [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) for more information.